# javascript - jQuery mobile execute transition after function finish

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm currently using the current bit of html for jQuery Mobile page transitions:

```
<a href="#page2" data-role="button" data-transition="flip" onclick="save()">page2</a>
```

The `save()` function here is something that saves the `canvas` on the current page.

It seems however the `save()` function runs asynchronously along with the page transition and hence at times the page transitions without having managed to fully save the information I wanted it to.

Is there a way to completely finish a function before jQuery Mobile executes the page transition?

--**update**--

Here's a jsFiddle example for all to play around with:

http://jsfiddle.net/nMR85/1291/

(notice the `pagebeforechange` firing before the `save trigger` in the console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this solution:

```
var transition = false;

function save() {

    if(!transition) {
        var callback = function() {
            transition = true;
            $("a").click();
        };

        // your aynchronous code which will trigger callback after it finishes executing

        return false;
    }
    else {
        transition = false;
    }
}
```

First execution of this function will not trigger transition (`return false` prevents from executing every next event handler attached). Second execution will, but will not trigger sending. Of course putting `transition` variable into global context is not a good practice, but it's just an idea how you can cope with this problem.

Also I think that inside onclick (in HTML) you should have `return save()`.

---

EDIT ACCORDING TO THE PROVIDED FIDDLE:

Playing with the fiddle I have changed `a` element a little bit:

```
<a id="goto_trigger" href="#p2" data-role="button" onclick="return save()">Go To Page 2 with return</a>
```

Also Script should looks like this:

```
$(document).bind('pagebeforechange', function(e, data) {
    console.log("pagebeforechange");
});

var transition = false;

function save() {
    if(!transition) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            alert("save trigger");
            transition = true;
            $("#goto_trigger").click();
        },3000);
        return false;
    }
};
```

Now it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it sadly doesn't work. I've also tried `onclick="return false"` just to experiment, but even despite the `return false` the page change is triggered.

Comment: I've posted a simplified jsFiddle example, hope it helps.

Comment: I've realised that the transition is triggering despite the `return false` due to the AngularJs jqm adapter I'm currently using. If you could put up a modification of the example I put up on jsfiddle using the method you've outlined, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @dk123 - I have just done it. Code is working with provided jsFiddle.

Comment: Thanks, this works great :D Here's the modified jsFiddle with your implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/nMR85/1292/